# Kotlin-Multiplatform - no Jar Files downloaded on Gradle depedencies after Upload-Publish on Bintray

Tags: gradle, bintray, kotlin-multiplatform

I was able to publish my work on bintray a while a go, when I try it out on a test project

```kotlin
repositories {
  maven("https://dl.bintray.com/user/libraries/")
}

dependencies { 
   implementation("com.user.project:project-name:version")
}
```

I get no error on Gradle build.

I can see my jar files on  `https://dl.bintray.com/user/libraries/`

```
com/
  user/
     project/
           projec-name/
             | -- maven-metadata.xml
             | -- version
                     | -- pom.xml
                     | -- project-name-version-jvm.jar
                     | -- project-name-meta-data-version-sources.jar
                     | -- project-name-meta-data-version.jar
```

upload on bintray seem nothing is wrong

On IntelliJ under Gradle tab on right side pane, the project is listed on `runtimeClassPath`
but non on `compileClassPath` also no jar file downloaded from `External Dependencies`

here is my

**build.gradle.kts**

```kotlin
publishing {
    publications {
        create<MavenPublication>("project-name") {
            pom {
                name.set("project-name")
                description.set("My project descriptoin")
                url.set("https://github.com/user/project-name")

                licenses {
                    license {
                        name.set("Apache License 2.0")
                        url.set("https://github.com/user/project-name/blob/master/LICENSE")
                    }
                }
                developers {
                    developer {
                        id.set("user")
                        name.set("user")
                    }
                }
                scm {
                    connection.set("scm:git:git://github.com/user/project-name.git")
                    url.set("https://github.com/user/project-name")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

bintray {
    user = "user"
    key = "key"

    pkg(delegateClosureOf<BintrayExtension.PackageConfig> {
        repo = "libraries"
        name = "project-name"
        userOrg = "user"
        setPublications("project-name") // should be same as set in Maven Publication above
        filesSpec(delegateClosureOf<CopySpec> {
            from("build/libs/")
            into("com/user/project/project-name/version") // this i think where the issue is, altho can't verify
        })

    })
}
```

but why I can't get any jars when I put it on my project via dependencies.

I would greatly appreciate some insights on where I did it wrong

**Extra Question**: If I am targeting JVM only at the moment, Is it safe to remove all other jars except with `jvm` as suffix.

Answer (score 0):

The uploaded artifacts do not match the Maven layout.

The main artifact should be called `project-name-version.jar`. The presence of `-meta-data` in the source and alternate JARs also mean they will not be considered as archives with classifiers for Maven.

That said Gradle should complain about not finding that JAR.

Which task did you use for testing consumption?

Comment: as you said `project-name-version.jar` should be the main artifact.

I was using kotlin-multiplatform, after build it generates those  jars accordingly  to target platform. I am new to publishing libraries. so im not sure what should be the right thing. I followed the instruction exactly here: https://github.com/bintray/gradle-bintray-plugin#readme

Comment: Kotlin multiplatform requires Gradle Module Metadata to work properly. However the bintray plugin is not yet compatible with its publication - see https://github.com/bintray/gradle-bintray-plugin/issues/229